# Why does the unity mesh memory increase when it is rendered for the first time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory-management, mesh

In my game, I created many game objects, made them inactive and assigned meshes(shared meshes) to those game objects' MeshFilter component. This consumed some mesh memory(viewed in unity profiler). But this mesh memory got increased when all the game objects were brought within the frustrum(i.e., when the meshes are being rendered first). What is the additional memory consumption?